# How to access DOM event-handlers for JSX-components in server-sided React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I am building a simple static view-engine using React with the goal of rendering static HTML-markup and generating a js-file filled with that components DOM-events (onClick, etc).

The way I'm doing the first part is to require a specified JSX-file which, for example, looks like this:

```
import React from 'React';

export default class Test extends React.Component {

    clicked() {
        alert('Clicked the header!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{this.props.title}</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1 onClick={this.clicked}>click me!!!</h1>
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}
```

I am then rendering the JSX-file via a NodeJS-backend like this:

```
let view = require('path-to-the-jsx-file');
view = view.default || view;

const ViewElement = React.createFactory(view);
let output = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(ViewElement(props));
```

It works great for serving static HTML. But I am wondering if there is a way to access all components used in the JSX-file in an array or something, which I then could use to check what events are bound and to which handlers.

So in this example, be able to get that the `<h1>`-tag's `onClick`-handler? Is this even possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a **lot** of messing around I came up with a solution that works quite well.

If I create my own instance of the `ReactElement` I want to render (in the example `ViewElement(props)`), I can then render the element using it's standard `render`-function:

```
let element = ViewElement(props);
let instance = new element.type();
let render = instance.render();
```

From here I can go through all the props for this element, so, say, `onClick`-handlers would be in `render.props`.

So what I do is to check each prop if the key matches a react-event-name (ex. onClick, onDragEnd, onDragEnter etc). If it does, and the value of this property is of type function - I have the event-name **and** it's handler-function:

```
Object.keys(render.props).map((key) => {
    if (bigArrayOfAllTheEventNames.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        item.events[key] = render.props[key];//check if type is function.
    }
});
```

Then I also iterate through the `render.props.children` recursivly to reach all it's child components and add every component which has events to an array.

The only problem left was that I needed a way to bind the rendered DOM-string to the javascript handlers I now have. For this I added a need to use a custom DOM-attribute, which then can be used to ID the component with something like this

`$("[data-id=value]").on({event-name}, {it's JS-handler})`.

It might not be perfect yet, but I think that this is the *best* solution out there.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to get the function as a string from the onClick event, we want the following:

1. The DOM of the element

   - We can obtain this by attaching a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) attribute on our h1 element
2. The name of the function being passed into the onClick event (clicked)
3. The function itself from a string containing the name of the function

   - Since we're conveniently using methods within a React component, we can use this['functionName'] within our component to obtain the function.
4. A stringified version of the function

---

```
import React from 'React';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        // Gets the name of the function passed inside onClick()
        const nameBound = this.element.props.onClick.name;

        // Removes 'bound ' from the function name (-> clicked)
        const nameString = nameBound.replace('bound ', '');

        // Gets the function from the function name as a string
        const convertedFunction = this[nameString];

        // Converts the function into string
        const stringifiedFunction = convertedFunction.toString();
        console.log(functionString);
    }

    clicked() {
        alert('Clicked the header!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{this.props.title}</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1 ref={(element) => { this.element = element; }} onClick={this.clicked}>click me!!!</h1>
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it would be quite hard to maintain. Imagine having 5-10 handlers in that component. And I'm not sure how you would be able to get that data back to the backend, unless you had like a master-component which had a function that did this somehow.